# How a new target can call a previous target with additional arguments?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have such code snippet:

```
.PHONY: program1 program2

a=A
b=B
c=C

program1: 
    @python example.py a=$(a) b=$(b)

program2:
    program1 c=$(c) d=d
```

Due to the DRY principle, I don't want to replicate code and composed `program2` in a way calling `program1`.

But I understand that `program1` is not in a path.

How can I correctly define `program2` target?

Answer (score 0):

The recipe of a rule contains *shell* commands.  `make` does not execute them directly.  The shell it uses to execute them does not recognize `make` target names as commands any more than any other shell does, so a recipe cannot use `make` targets as commands.

But a recipe *can* run `make`, a procedure conventionally described as "recursive make".  For example, this rule would achieve what I think you are describing:

```
program2:
        $(MAKE) program1 c='$(c)' d=d
```

The `MAKE` variable will normally expand to the name of make command you used -- often just `make`, but perhaps something like `gmake` or `/special/path/make`.  You can also redefine it yourself inside the makefile, maybe to add flags to it, for example.